# Saving contenteditable data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to save a `contenteditable` `div`'s data locally with jQuery.
Here is whatever I've done: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XNkaY/11/)

Please help me I'm stuck on this!

Comment: What is the question son?

Comment: Please click on the link...

Comment: I did, please clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve and which part doesn't work.

Comment: You can see that I've used a textarea and the jquery code is working to save the textarea data locally.
but I'm unable to figure out how to save a contenteditable div's(instead of the textarea) data..

Comment: I've updated the link please check it- http://jsfiddle.net/XNkaY/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the "textarea" element to "div" and add contenteditable="true". Then change text.value to text.innerHTML. Is that what you mean? It seems to work for me at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XNkaY/12/).

```
<div id="editor" contentEditable="true" placeholder="Start writing..."></div>
...
[text.innerHTML || text.placeholder], {
...
session.text = text.innerHTML;
```

Comment: This what I wanted! thanks.
But is it possible to remove the html tags from the saved file but to keep the text only?

Comment: @john ...should be able to save the text only, but from the little I understand, I think this script may be defining the "$" in such a way that the jQuery .text() function would not be available. So using this script might require a little rewriting, or constructing your own replacement function for unwanted HTML tags. I do see the tags added for <br> &gt; &lt; etc. in the saved file.

Comment: @groovy I think using textarea would be better idea instead!