# Get innerHtml but remove unwanted tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know that how can i get innerHtml without the html tags. Only the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not using jQuery (or even if you are), this link explores some of the different options (eg innerText vs textContent), along with how they differ between browsers:

http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/

Basically, not all approaches work in all browsers, and some strip line breaks while others don't.

Answer (score 5):

if you're using jquery, use `$('myelem').text()`.

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @john - Why don't you ask this on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795072/saving-contenteditable-data-using-jquery)?

Comment: @Derek I think the context is different!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the text() function instead:

Use `$("your_element").text()`

You can use also:

```
document.getElementById("your_element").textContent;
```