# How to get only text from html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text, gettext

I have query some data and result is like this

```
<p><img src="xxx.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br></p><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br></p>
```

show on console. I want to remove all html tag from this data and get only string like this

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type.

Anyone know how to remove single and double quote from this data or some solution. Thanks

Comment: use `.text()` to get t ext only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append & try this simple jQuery

```
<div id="output"><div>

<Script type="text/javascript">
  $("#output").html($("p").text());
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a temporary element and read it's `.textContent` property:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = htmlContent;
var textContent = d.textContent || d.innerText;
```

If you can use jQuery:

```
var textContent = $('<div/>').html(htmlContent).text();
```

Answer (score 6):

Using regular expression

```js
function RemoveHTMLTags(html) {
  var regX = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;                
  alert(html.replace(regX, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($('p').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><img src="xxx.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br></p><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br></p>
```

Use `.text()` to get t ext only

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using `innerHTML`

In your JavaScript do

```
var a = document.getElementById("para") //Let us say your paragraph id is "para"

var b - a.innerHTML;
```

Now `b` would contain the string in the paragraph.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("para");

var b = a.innerHTML;
alert(b);
```

```html
<p><img src="xxx.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;"/><br></p> 
<p id = "para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br></p>
```

You can also Read Mozilla Documentation of [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Also I found this Wonderful [Guide](http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/) that would help you out in the future too and which explain the difference between `innerHTML` , `innerText` and `textcontent`.

Also Look At This Question [Get innerHtml but remove unwanted tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795441/get-innerhtml-but-remove-unwanted-tags)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getTextOnly(){
  var pTag = document.getElementById("page");
  textOnly = pTag.innerHTML;
  textOnly = textOnly.replace("<br>"," ");
  alert(textOnly);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><img src="xxx.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br></p><p id="page">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br></p>

    <button onclick="getTextOnly()" >Show Text</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

How about this? If you want to get only text inside of `<p>` tag, you should set id for this `<p>` tag. Just advice.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you need to take into consideration,
a) If you want to get the text of all the DOM elements of a specific type or not.

If you do then use the following :

```
<div>
  A lot of content here
</div>

var data = $('div');
console.log(data.innerHTML);
```

Else add a class or id to the element/elements respectively whose data you require and then use the above code, but substitute "div" for your class/id.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way and vanilla Javascript way too in this example:

```js
//jQuery way:
console.log($('p').text())

// OR can be using vanilla JS:
let para = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // this can be also by getElementById()

console.log(para[1].innerText);// we are using [1] because we have two <p> tags
```

```html
<p><img src="xxx.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br></p><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br></p>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```