# How to find a word with HTML tags inside

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, full-text-search

I am trying to solve this problem on typescript (Angular 12):

I want to find the word **tempor** in the following string (**tempor** is just an example, can be any word):

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <em>amet</em>, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod te<b>m</b>por incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

The problem is that the word can contains any html code inside, Ex: **`te<b>m</b>por`**, **`<em>tem</em>por`** , **`tem<a>por<a/>`**, etc.

Also, I cannot use regular expressions, because a word can contain any html inside and we consider an infinite number of words that the user can enter, therefore it is not possible to use regular expressions as a pattern.

I was looking for some npm but couldn't find anything that can solve the problem.

In short, I need to find the word without the html tags, but I need to also preserve the html in terms of representing the style, some business rules, etc.

Does anyone know how to solve it or do you know an npm that can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866933/how-to-get-only-text-from-html-tag?rq=1

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with the search. Just confirm word exists? Extract the word and html? Or other? Please also show what you have tried

Comment: I need to know if the word exists and where it exists, preserving the html. I have tried to search with regex but it is impossible as the user can search for any word.

Comment: What does preserving the html mean though? You haven't explained what you are wanting to do with the results

Answer (score 2):

`element.textContent` gives you only text without tags. You can find your desired string: `element.textContent.indexOf('tempor') !== -1`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try this way.

```
let text = document.querySelector('p')?.textContent;
console.log(text?.search('tempor'));//72
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when answering a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)